# Implementing Toggle Switches using UIButtons?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uibutton, uialertview

I have two buttons, one named "On", and the other named "Off". They are placed on the main view controller.

When the user presses the "On" button, I want it so that when they click on other views such as "sound view" and "vocal view", that a `UIAlertView` pops up. So the "On" button activates the `UIAlertView`s, but once the user presses the "Off" button, all the `UIAlertView`s are disabled.

Answer (score 0):

Create an toggle button method and call this method from your buttons. Your method should be like this:

```
onButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140,25,160,20)];
offButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140,125,160,20)];
- (void) toggleButton: (UIButton *) button 
{ 
 if(button == onButton )
{

    // do whatever you want
}
else if(button == offButton )
{
    // do whatever you want
}
```

I did not write the method inside the if clause but i hope you see what i mean.

Comment: But that will only work in 1 view right? I need it so once the user clicked the on button, it occurs on all the views which i set it to.

Comment: Thats not a problem. Create an global boolean variable (create instance on AppDelegate) that keep this on/off information. You can check this any of your class.

Comment: Okay in still new at this so im still learning, when i build it i get 'error: initializer element is not constant' on the lines uibutton = on and uibutton = off

Comment: I straight copied and pasted your code, im not too sure of the implementation

Comment: ok then create instance of button on header file then assign it inside the method. I mean do this: UIButton* onB; UIButton* offB inside the .h file then do check my post again i edit the code part

Comment: @interface MainerViewController : UIViewController {
 IBOutlet UIButton *onButton;
 IBOutlet UIButton *offButton;

}

I already entered these and the error still persists

Comment: You do not need to write IBOutlet. Are you sure you use the code above because i have used exactly the same code and it works. Can you send the exact error sentence here?

Comment: @implementation MainerViewController

UIButton *onButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140,25,160,20)];
UIButton *offButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(140,125,160,20)];

- (void) toggleButton: (UIButton *) button 
{ 
 if(button == onButton )
 {
  
  // do whatever you want
 }
 else if(button == offButton )
 {
  // do whatever you want
 }
}
 - This is the .m with the error of /Users/user/Desktop/dbAudio copy/Classes/MainerViewController.m:21:0 /Users/user/Desktop/dbAudio copy/Classes/MainerViewController.m:21: error: initializer element is not constant